# What does SAMBA use /tmp for?

Tags: samba, tmp

I just had a major issue with Samba, I changed my /tmp permissions to something rather restrictive, and after this point I could not log in to samba from any windows client (I did not try a linux client, didn't have one on hand). (Changed permissions back to something less restrictive, all works fine again)

My question is, what exactly is samba using /tmp for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do that.

There're [plenty system calls](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html) that creates temp files and directories in /tmp, including:

> - Function: FILE * tmpfile (void)
> - Function: FILE * tmpfile64 (void)
> - Function: char * tmpnam (char *result)
> - Function: char * tmpnam_r (char *result)
> - Macro: int L_tmpnam
> - Macro: int TMP_MAX
> - Function: char * tempnam (const char *dir, const char *prefix)
> - SVID Macro: char * P_tmpdir
> - Function: char * mktemp (char *template)
> - Function: int mkstemp (char *template)
> - Function: char * mkdtemp (char *template)

Which is probably why samba crashes ...

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'm running a server though, I don't need very many things to function properly (mostly just samba to be honest)

Comment: perhaps so, but randomly changing and disabling things you don't understand is never a good idea.  BTW, by "something less restrictive", i hope you meant "back to what it was, `chmod 1777 /tmp`".

Comment: @cas Late answer, but my permission changes were done in the mount options (fstab) I never actually changed the directory permission directly (I was mounting tmpfs). Btw I accepted this answer, but only because it doesn't seem like I'll get another one (I.e. what exactly samba is using tmp for) it might very well be one or a couple of the functions on your provided list though.